# Folder deletion with a force parameter no longer working

Tags: box-api

I have an integration that utilizes Box's API.  One of the API calls we have implemented is the "Delete a Folder" API.  Yesterday my calls were working correctly, but something has changed and the force parameter is no longer working for deleting a folder with contents.

The URL that is being hit by my call is:
https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/349215357?force=true

The error message in the json body of the response I'm receiving is:
Folder not empty

This was working yesterday, so something has changed between then and now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter was update to be 'recursive' instead of 'force' to reflect its actual functionality. We updated [the blog post](http://developers.blog.box.com/2012/07/13/more-v2-updates/) and [documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-delete-a-folder) to reflect this.

Comment: Is there an rss feed or some kind of stream I can subscribe to to be notified of changes to the API?

Comment: You could follow the RSS stream for the API blog posts on http://developers.blog.box.com/